# Issue with New-JiraIssue cmdlet after Jira Update

Tags: powershell, jira-rest-api

I'm currently facing an issue with a PowerShell script that interacts with our Reservation API and creates new Jira issues using the New-JiraIssue cmdlet. Since the recent Jira update, I'm encountering the following error:

Problem very simplified:

```
New-JiraIssue -Project PERS -IssueType Personalisierung -Credential $Cred -Summary 'Test issue from PowerShell'
```

Error Message:

```
The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet.
```

Interestingly, the following code snippet works perfectly fine:

```
$JQLQuery = 'project = Personalisierung AND status != Abgeschlossen AND status != Zurückgestellt'
$Issues = Get-JiraIssue -Query $JQLQuery -Credential $Credential
Write-Host $Issues # Outputs a list of issues
```

It seems to be related to the New-JiraIssue cmdlet specifically after the recent Jira update.

Comment: Have you tried updating the PowerShell module to the latest version too?

Comment: you call `New-JiraIssue` that fails, but its weird that `Get-JiraIssue` snippet worked? Other than that, looking at the `New-JiraIssue` cmdlet code there are 5 terminating error's that can cause this behaviour https://github.com/AtlassianPS/JiraPS/blob/master/JiraPS/Public/New-JiraIssue.ps1